# How to install skype on ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, skype

I tried `sudo apt-get install skype` and it shows `Unable to locate package skype`

How should I install it ?

Comment: Did you check here? http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64 FYI: Skype is not Free Software and therefore not in the main repository.

Comment: Add the repository: sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ quantal partner" >> /etc/apt/sources.list' then just sudo apt-get install skype

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the .deb file from [skype.com](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/)
2. Select Ubuntu 12.04 (multiarch) in the drop down menu.
3. Double left-click on the .deb file it downloads. Ubuntu Software Center should handle the installation.

Answer (score 0):

you can activate in the repository the programs of partners and you can do
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install skype
end it's all, ubuntu it's characterized by the easiest forms to do something